# What would be an idiomatic way in kotlin to generate a list of items by calling a function?

Tags: list, kotlin

Let's say there is a function that returns a single nullable return value. For instance:

```
fun getItem(): String?
```

I'd like to create a new list of items by calling this function until it returns `null`.

My idea would be to write an iterator that iterates the return value until it's `null`. However, is there a more elegant or idiomatic way to approach this issue?

Comment: `val list = generateSequence(::getItem).toList()`. Not sure if that's idiomatic, but it's one option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @Slaw says in the comments, you can use [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) and pass it a reference to your function (or a lambda that calls it if you want) to create a `Sequence` that generates values. Terminating when your function returns `null` is built-in behaviour:

> Returns a sequence which invokes the function to calculate the next value on each iteration until the function returns null.

So you can literally just do `generateSequence(::getItem)` to get your "iterator", and call `toList` or [whatever sequences function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/) you like on it. It's not an actual `Iterator` though - you can get one of those by doing `toList()` and then calling `iterator()` on that.

There's a bunch of ways to get this functionality, but `generateSequence` is the simplest I think. If you needed more control, you could chain a `takeWhile()` call to make a sequence that terminates on a specific condition/value, or you could use the [`sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html) builder function to `yield` the items you need (say if you wanted to have nulls in there). And there's non-sequence approaches like @Alex.T's "add to a list" trick too (although - I haven't checked - I'd imagine that's what `generateSequence -> toList` is doing under the hood)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I had to use the slightly different syntax with the call `generateSequence { getItem() }.toList()`.

Comment: @LicensedSlacker yeah you can wrap the call in a lambda if you like, but the direct function reference (``::getIem``) should work too: https://pl.kotl.in/z8NFaqSFg

Comment: @LicensedSlacker For more information on the syntax: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what would be idiomatic tbh, but you can use a simple `while(true)` to achieve it.

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>()

while (true) getItem()?.let { list += it } ?: break
```

That basically translates to:

```
while true (infinite loop).
if getItem() is not null, add it to the list.
if getItem() is null, then break the loop.
```